# How to npm build inside Docker with multiple layers of private repo dependencies

Tags: docker, github, npm

Does anyone know how to do an npm install inside a Docker that has to access multiple dependencies of GitHub repos?  I've got the following situation where I have to npm install from a private repo (I have permission to), but the top project sucks in other repos from the same organization.  Such as:

> npm i bob/top-foo

top-foo's package.json has

```
  "dependencies": {
    "middle-foo": "bob/middle-foo",
```

middle-foo's package.json has

```
  "dependencies": {
    "bottom-foo": "bob/bottom-foo",
```

I don't have a problem running this as me from my Linux environment as I have my ssh loaded up into my GitHub account.  The problem is, of course, that the Docker image fires up as root and I can't seem to figure out how push credentials to flow down into the dependency installations.

My Docker file is kinda bare boned at the moment since I can't even get the key to authenticate.  I created a brand new one with ssh-keygen and am attempting to use it:

```
FROM node:6

ARG git_personal_access_token
RUN echo $git_personal_access_token
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY

RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN chmod 700 /root/.ssh
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN echo $SSH_PRIVATE_KEY > /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN chmod 600 /root/.ssh/id_rsa

RUN eval $(ssh-agent);ssh-add;ssh -vvv -T -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa git@github.com
```

Comment: also if you can share some of your Dockerfile details?

Comment: @kakabali I couldn't get a properly formatted comment, so I edited the original post.

Comment: ARG does not seem wise: a docker history of your image would reveal your secret key...

Comment: I've just been trying various ways, just to get it doing anything. Not much luck.  I'm all for better alternatives.

Comment: @kakabali I was able to create a deploy key and use it for the top level repo, but I couldn't use it for the dependency repos in the organization. Is a machine user a better alternative? This eventually all has to go into a docker that's building an embedded image.

Answer (score 1):

> I don't have a problem running this as me from my Linux environment as I have my ssh loaded up into my GitHub account.

Then you need to embed ssh keys *encrypted* into your docker image.
Not your own ssh private keys, but new **[deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/v3/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys)** ones created just for that, and whose public keys are registered to the relevant repos (as opposed to be registered to your account).

See "[Automating pushing parts of a git repo to google cloud bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50083423/6309)": the idea is to have a script which would decrypt those private encrypted deploy ssh keys and put them in the `~/root/.ssh` container at runtime, allowing docker to access those private repo.

Comment: I saw this, but I think a wrinkle is these aren't repos I own outright, but can access as part of the team I'm on in my org.  I can do pushes and merges, etc, on the repo, I don't see a "setting" option that will let me add a key.

Comment: @tranzmatt Any possibility to contact the org admins, and register a deploy key through them?

Comment: I'll have to give it a go.

Comment: I was able to create a deploy key and use it for the top level repo, but I couldn't use it for the dependency repos in the organization.  Is a machine user a better alternative?  This eventually all has to go into a docker that's building an embedded image.